# Can I create multiple model instances with CreateView?

Tags: django

I have a form whose purpose is to let a user add, edit, subtract and reorder songs. JavaScript DOM manipulation lets users add, subtract and reorder songs fields. The reordering is via jQuery UI's [sortable interaction](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/). The order of songs is crucial.

HTML field name attribute values are duplicated. I'm not using Django to generate the form.

Assuming there are two songs on submission, Firebug shows the form DOM looking something like this (csrf omitted):

```
<form method="post" action="/save/">
    <ul id="sortable_songs" class="ui-sortable">
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="song_txt_1">
            <textarea id="more_info_txtarea_1" name="more_info"></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="song_txt_2">
            <textarea id="more_info_txtarea_2" name="more_info"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <button type="submit">save</button>
</form>
```

Example query string:

```
title=FOO&more_info=FOO+INFO&title=BAR&more_info=BAR+INFO
```

The model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #todo: foreignkey to User
```

Probably not much data is involved, both in each record and with regard to the number of records per user. Hence I'm assuming it makes sense that, for a given user, when the form is submitted I'll delete all of their song instances in the Song table and create a bunch of new ones according to the form. (As opposed to having to edit existing records and having a db field which indicates song order).

It seems like I shouldn't write my own view so I'm trying Django's generic `CreateView`, but perhaps unsurprisingly, with the above user input only a model instance with "BAR" and "BAR INFO" is created -no "FOO" instance is made.

Is there a simple way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/), in this way you can manage multiple instances of an object in a simple way, however you need to control some extra variables and format your query string. But all is covered in the documentation.

You will need a `order` field in your model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=65)
    more_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #todo: foreignkey to User
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        order_by = ['order']
        # to ensure database integrity
        unique_thogeter = [(user, order)]
```

you may also need to update your create view,

```
class SongListCreate(CreateView):
    model = Song

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(SongListCreate, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        # add a song formset to the context
        # or a bound formset from validation
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        formset = SongFormset(#post data)
        objects = formset.save(commit = False)
        objects.update(#user instance, 
        #and other data you might need like the new orders)
        objects.save()
        return super(SongListCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

This is roughly what you may need to do, working with formsets is quite a bit hard while you get used to.

You may also want to use a custom library to manage the order of the songs easily, like moving up or down, something like [django-positions](https://github.com/jpwatts/django-positions).

Regards.

Comment: I might well be missing something but aren't Formsets for multiple forms?